# Checking type parameter of a generic method in C#

Tags: c#, generics, typechecking

Is it possible to do something like this in C#:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T t)  
{
    if (T is MyClass)
    {
        MyClass mc = (MyClass)t 
        ...
    }
    else if (T is List<MyClass>)
    {
        List<MyClass> lmc = (List<MyClass>)t
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Yes:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyClass))
{
    MyClass mc = (MyClass)(object) t;
}
else if (typeof(T) == typeof(List<MyClass>))
{
    List<MyClass> lmc = (List<MyClass>)(object) t;
}
```

It's slightly odd that you need to go via a cast to object, but that's just the way that generics work - there aren't as many conversions from a generic type as you might expect.

Of course another alternative is to use the normal execution time check:

```
MyClass mc = t as MyClass;
if (mc != null)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    List<MyClass> lmc = t as List<MyClass>;
    if (lmc != null)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That will behave differently to the first code block if `t` is null, of course.

I would *try* to avoid this kind of code where possible, however - it can be necessary sometimes, but the idea of generic methods is to be able to write *generic* code which works the same way for any type.

Comment: I actually have a little more complicated issue. What if MyClass derives from MyBaseClass and there are many more MyClasses all of which deriving from MyBaseClass?

Comment: @synergetic: You've described the type hierarchy, but not what you want to do with it. You can use reflection (e.g. `typeof(T).BaseType` or `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(...)` to explore the type hierarchy if that's useful. I'd still try to avoid it if possible though :)

Comment: Hate to be a wet towel here, but this answer falls short in cases where T is actually a boxed type  (ex: object boxedMyClass = new MyClass()). In cases like this, the type returned by the typeof operator will be object, not MyClass, causing the above typeof check to fail. In my opinion, this is where C# falls short as a language: dealing with both generic type vetting & complex ontological logic (ex. there's no way to say something like "aLifeform is Mammal and not Bear" in C# w/o getting into reflection).

Comment: @rmiesen: It's not clear what you mean here. Note that boxing doesn't get involved in the first place for *classes*. `T` will be whatever you specify it to be, but it's the *compile-time* type. If you want the *execution-time* type of an object, call `GetType`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I would like to avoid such implementation (*God method* that's able to digest any type) but am not able to see how to do it without runtime type checking. Suppose the generic method's signature is something like: `T Obfuscate<T>(T value) where T : IConvertible` so it can obfuscate value types and strings (let's pretend enums are not part of `IConvertible`). **How can one implement such generic method without implementing it for each individual passed type value?** http://stackoverflow.com/q/23957027/75642

Answer (score 15):

Starting with C# 7, you can do this in a concise way with the `is` operator:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T value)  
{
    if (value is MyClass mc)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (value is List<MyClass> lmc)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

See documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is

Answer (score 10):

It's 2017 and we have now C# 7 with pattern matching. If your type T inherit `object` you can you code like this

```
void Main()
{
    DoSomething(new MyClass { a = 5 });
    DoSomething(new List<MyClass> { new MyClass { a = 5 }, new MyClass { a = 5 }});
}


public void DoSomething(object t)
{
    switch (t)
    {
        case MyClass c:
            Console.WriteLine($"class.a = {c.a}");
            break;
        case List<MyClass> l:
            Console.WriteLine($"list.count = {l.Count}");
            break;
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public int a { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Just to note that you can't use this for generics until C# 7.1.

Comment: You can if you box it (which is what the C# 7.1 compiler does behind the scenes anyway).

Comment: If you have a second type with the same property name, let's say a MyClass2 and it also has a property "a" - is there a way to stack the two case statements for MyClass and MyClass2 so as to not have to repeat the same Console.WriteLine() statement?

Comment: You mean something like
`case MyClass c:
case MyClass2 d:`
It's not possible, according to documentation: _Neither of those variables is definitely assigned in this switch block. If either of these cases match, clearly one of the variables has been assigned. However, it's impossible to tell which has been assigned at compile time, because either case could match at runtime._

Answer (score 3):

I believe there's something wrong in your design. **You want to compare between types in an already generic method. Generics are meant to deal with type-variable situation.** I recommend to do it this way..

```
//Generic Overload 1
public void DoSomething<T>(T t)
    where T : MyClass
{
    ...
}

//Generic Overload 2
public void DoSomething<T>(T t)
    where T : List<MyClass>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: For that matter, you can just drop the generics and specify the type of your parameter. But +1 because I wanted to have polymorphism without parameters.

Comment: How exactly does this work?  As pointed out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367032/member-with-the-same-signature-already-defined-with-different-type-constraints "you can't overload by generic constraints".