# Can´t have two methods with same signature but different generic constraints

Tags: c#, generics

I have this method:

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> DoSomething<TResult>(Func<MyType, TResult> func) 
    where TResult : AnotherType
```

Now I want this method to also appear for `IEnumerable<AnotherType>`. So I wrote this which apparently doesn´t compile:

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> DoSomething<TResult>(Func<MyType, TResult> func) 
    where TResult : IEnumerable<AnotherType>
```

I get the compiler-error:

> Member with the same signature already declared

I read [Member with the same signature already defined with different type constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15367091/2528063) which deals members with another return-type. However in my example I don´t distinguish on the methods return-type but on its param-list which is `Func<MyType, TResult>` in the first place and `Func<IEnumerable<MyType>, TResult>` in the second one. However the compiler can´t handle this.

Is there another way than having another method-name for the second example?

Comment: Generic Constraints are not part of a method signature and thus you cannot create teo identical methods with different constraints.

Comment: If you're defining the type anyway, why is it generic at all instead of being `Func<MyType, AnotherType>` in one and `Func<MyType, IEnumerable<AnotherType>>` in the other?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Whoops, haven't noticed the link, sorry.

Comment: [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/) post in Eric Lippert's blog is an interesting read about the subject. The comments show that the design decision was somewhat controversial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true that two method overloads are not allowed to differ solely by the generic constraint.

In your case I wonder if you even need `TResult` (as was also commented by Alfie Goodacre) becuause `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant in `T` and `Func<in T1, out TResult>` is covariant in `TResult`.

So try:

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> DoSomething(Func<MyType, AnotherType> func)
```

and:

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> DoSomething(Func<MyType, IEnumerable<AnotherType>> func)
```

Because of the mentioned covariances, it will be fine to use a class more derived than `AnotherType` when calling the above overloads.

---

Another option:

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> DoSomething<TResult>(Func<MyType, TResult> func) 
  where TResult : AnotherType
```

and:

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> DoSomething<TResult>(Func<MyType, IEnumerable<TResult>> func) 
  where TResult : AnotherType
```

In this alternative approach, the signatures differ and the constraint is the same in both overloads. This can work even if `AnotherType` is an `interface` and `TResult` is a `struct` (value type) implementing the interface, a situation in which covariance (`out T` and `out TResult`) does not work.

Comment: Oh dear, simpliest solutions are allways the best ones.