# How to cast T To Nullable<T>

Tags: c#

I have a generic method and need to guarantee that my method returns  `nullable<T>`(ex. source is  `List<int>` or  `List<int?>` must returns `int?`) and I want to return ***null*** instead of ***default*** (ex. default of ***int*** is ***0***. in this case I want to return ***null***). It can be possible to add constraints on type parameter(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) but whit this approach I must have 2 methods (one of them with *struct* constraint and another with *class* constraints)

my method is:

```
public static T? ElementOrNull<T>(List<T> source, int? index)
{
    if (source == null || index == null || source.Count <= index)
        return null;
    return source[index.Value];
}
```

I try `Convert.ChangeType()` and reflection(`Activator.CreateInstance()` and `Activator.CreateInstance<T?>()`) but I can't solve this problem.

Any and all feedback is appreciated. Thank you

***Note***: I checked all the questions about generics and casting of them in StackOverflow but they didn't help me

Comment: What's wrong with two overloads? You won't notice it's two of them when using them, the right one will always be used.

Comment: The problem is those two methods can not be overload. because the inputs, output and the name of the method are the same

Comment: They're not the same. One is `T?` which is shorthand for `Nullable<T>` and the other is `T`. Though they can't coexist because the name and input parameters are the same.

Comment: You have to use 2 methods because `int?` is actually `System.Nullable<int>`. If `T` is `class` then it would have to return raw `T`, but if `T` is `struct` it would have to return `Nullable<T>` which is wrapper. This cannot be expressed in dotnet's type system

Comment: If you allow `null` in the `List<T>` (i.e. `List<T?>`), the two methods will be valid overloads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nullable reference types: How to specify "T?" type without constraining to class or struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975211/nullable-reference-types-how-to-specify-t-type-without-constraining-to-class)

Comment: @GSerg Unfortunately, it didn't help, but "JL0PD" and "Theraot" solution worked for me

Comment: My C# is probably a little rusty and I haven't worked much with nullable types, but: (1) The title of your question doesn't make sense at all; (2) You don't give us any error message or undesired vs. desired behavior, so I don't even understand what your question is. Please explain better, and fix the title! Edit: Oh, The question mark in the title is part of the type, not part of a question! That makes more sense ;-).

Answer (score 3):

Generics constraints are not part of the method signature, but compiler still needs to know if `T` is value or reference type to convert `null` to `T` and handle `?` in `T?` correctly. But you can help the compiler using optional constrained parameters this way:

```
public class ReqStruct<T> where T : struct
{
}

public class ReqClass<T> where T : class
{
}

public static T? ElementOrNull<T>(List<T> source, int? index, ReqStruct<T> req = null) where T : struct
{
    if (source == null || index == null || source.Count <= index)
        return null;
    return source[index.Value];
}

public static T? ElementOrNull<T>(List<T> source, int? index, ReqClass<T> req = null) where T : class
{
    if (source == null || index == null || source.Count <= index)
        return null;
    return source[index.Value];
}
```

And since the parameters are optional the usage will look like:

```cs
var intOrNull = MethodHolder.ElementOrNull(new List<int> { 1 }, 5); // var is int?
var objOrNull = MethodHolder.ElementOrNull(new List<object>(), 5); // var is object?
```

Comment: I figured about this approach before but I can't change the signature of method Although this change be adding optional parameter

Comment: About this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367032 and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround/

Answer (score 3):

My preferred approach to this is to use a custom Option/[Maybe](https://github.com/AndreyTsvetkov/Functional.Maybe) type. I.e. a struct with a generic value and a bool to describe if the value is valid or not. I.e. never use null, always use a `Maybe` for optional parameters/return values:

```
public static Maybe<T> ElementOrNone<T>(List<T> source, Maybe<int> index)
{
    if (source == null || !index.HasValue || source.Count <= index.Value)
        return Maybe<T>.None;
    return source[index.Value];
}
```

While `Nullable<T>` and non-nullable references help to avoid null reference exceptions, I find them lacking when writing generic code, in part due to the problem you are describing.

Using a custom type have the advantage of consistent behavior for both value and reference types, and can allow for various extensions to make working with values easier, potentially even using linq query syntax to combine multiple values. A downside is that it is a custom type, so more to learn.