# Best way to implement a generic method in a type generic/agnostic way

Tags: c#, generics, factory-method

Suppose we have a generic method with such signature:

```
T Obfuscate<T>(T value) where T : IConvertible
```

I'm setting type constraint to `IConvertible` so this method can digest simple value types as well as strings. Let's forget for a moment that enums can also be supplied...

I would like to avoid such implementation that would check actual parameter type to execute correct processing.

```
// Please no GOD METHODS
public T Obfuscate<T>(T value)
    where T : IConvertible
{
    if (value is int)
    {
        ...
    }
    if (value is string)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This surely smells of a factory method, that would have to call particular implementation provider, but that would still require type checking.

**What would you suggest be best (hopefully generic approach) to this scenario?**

### Why a generic method?

I decided to have a generic method so it always returns correct type without the need to cast method returns in calling code.

Comment: The code you have shown does not really use generics, and there is no need for it to be a generic method. You could just as easily have `Obfuscate(IConvertible value)`. The code inside the method **wouldn't change**, which is usually a key sign that you aren't realy using generics.

Comment: What type of processing do you mean? You cant do any assumption except that your type is `IConvertible`.

Comment: @MarcGravell: But in that case one would require to cast method call return to correct type. Using a generic method ensures correct return type.

Comment: If the processing you do is dependent on the type of the argument, then this probably isn't a good candidate for generic construction.  If the processing only depends on it being IConvertible, then you shouldn't need type checking.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik ah, I didn't see the return type; yes, that could be an important factor, but without an indication of what happens in the `...` it is hard to say

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, you've got to perform type checking of *some* description. However, you can easily break it down into smaller methods and even have an open registration scheme:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, Delegate> obfuscators =
    new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>;

// Alternatively, register appropriate obfuscators on construction.
public void RegisterConverter<T>(Func<T, T> obfuscator)
{
    obfuscators[typeof(T)] = obfuscator;
}

public T Obfuscate<T>(T value)
{
    Delegate obfuscator;
    if (obfuscators.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out obfuscator)
    {
        // We know it'll be the right type...
        var realObfuscator = (Func<T, T>) obfuscator;
        return realObfuscator(value);
    }
    // ??? Throw exception? Return the original value?
}
```

Comment: Great Jon! I was thinking of using a dictionary with `Type` key... but apparently not thought it out to the very end. But the question is still whether this approach is best? Is there any better way of providing the same functionality but maybe without registering obfuscators beforehand?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: Well *something's* got to know how to obfuscate an `int` vs obfuscating a `string`. You've already said you don't want that information in the method... so where do you want to get it from?

Comment: Ok. So likely the best way is to create an `IObfuscator<T>` interface and register individual obfuscators with my **factory obfuscation class** (as shown here) that would store them in a static dictionary (reusability)? I'm just wondering whether there's a possibility of runtime being my factory so I would just say `someObj.Id = Obfuscate(someObj.Id)` and correct obfuscator would be used.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: Why have a separate interface? What benefit does that give you over `Func<T, T>`? And yes, if the compile-time type of `someObj.Id` is correct, type inference should work for you.

Comment: TDD. Suppose a base class that defines `void Obfuscate(obfuscatorFactory)`. Subclasses inheritingit. Suppose one with `int Id` and `string Name` properties. This class requires two obfuscators. Logic that would call `obj.Obfuscate(factory)` would have to provide factory and `obj` would call factory's `Obfuscate<T>(T value)` to actually obfuscate its values. TDD and manageability point it is better to have obfuscators implement an interface than be `Func<T,T>` within factory. Some may be complex and are better encapsulated in a class. **Did I explain myself in a clear way?**

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: Nope, not really - I don't see any significant difference in the testability of delegates vs interfaces. There's no need for the obfuscators to be within the factory - you can register them from anywhere else. Indeed, I prefer delegates in terms of testing, as you can use lambda expressions to *really* easily capture the value passed in etc. Much easier than creating your own fake implementation of an interface.

Comment: You're right about easily mocking obfuscator delegates, but the the other perspective of actual implementation is a different thing. I am using a complex process that would really be ugly contained in a single function. It's much better maintainable as a class instead. But I could use delegates and just point one to my class's public obfuscation method and not use interface. Although that would deviate from the codebase...

Comment: @Robert: So keep it in a separate class... It's still easy to create a delegate from that when you want to. Single method interfaces always make me reach for delegates...

Comment: I will. And one method interface is just in this example. There would actually be at least three...