# How can I write a generic function in c# which will call different functions based on the type of class?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-function

I have following generic class:

```
public class SearchModel<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    public List<T> result { get; set; }
}

public class A{
    ..
    ..
}

public class B{
    ..
    ..
}
```

and List in SearchModel class can be of type A/B.
Now I have these two function calls which gives me appropriate results.

```
public List<A> SearchApplicationsForA(SearchModel<A> model){
}

public List<B> SearchApplicationsForB(SearchModel<B> model){
}
```

I was wondering if I can write a generic function which can identify the type of T and calls respective functions. For eg.

```
    public List<T> SearchApplications<T>(SearchModel<T> model)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(A))
        {
            return SearchVerificationsForA(model);
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
        {
            return SearchApplicationsForB(model);
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to write such functions?

Comment: Take a look at this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004508/checking-type-parameter-of-a-generic-method-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You don't need a generic method when your code inside it isn't generic.

Comment: Wouldn't interfaces be your best friend here?

Comment: make an overload for a specific type. not all methods need to be generic

Answer (score 0):

Could you not

```
public List<A> SearchApplications(SearchModel<A> model) {
    return SearchVerificationsForA(model);
}

public List<B> SearchApplications(SearchModel<B> model) {
    return SearchVerificationsForB(model);
}
```

and not even bother with testing the type?

Comment: This would unquestionably work, except it is using function overloading, not a generic object. It is quite possibly the direction the OP *should* go; but doesn't really answer the question stated.

Comment: yes I agree, this is more a possible option.

Comment: I already have two separate functions calls for methods mentioned above but was checking if there is a better way to code this.

Comment: @coder_kp but notice that both of my functions are named the same thing? http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/method-overloading/ *Edit* wrong link

Answer (score 0):

You should consider this syntax instead:

```
public List<T> SearchApplications<T>(SearchModel<T> model)
{
    if (model is A)
    {
        return SearchVerificationsForA(model);
    }
    else if (model is B)
    {
        return SearchApplicationsForB(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but those two functions calls are failing to compile because of invalid arguments. This may be because the expected parameter is a template parameter for both.