# Determining generic type in base class

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following classes. `AuthorTest` and `BookTest` both inherit from `MyBaseClass`, which has a method `AddName` that takes in a generic param.

```
public class Book {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Author {
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}

public class BookTest : MyBaseClass {
    Book book = // book object

    base.AddName<Book>(book);
}

public class AuthorTest : MyBaseClass {
    Author author = // author object

    base.AddName<Author>(author);
}

public interface IMyBaseClass {
    void AddName<T>(T item);
}

public class MyBaseClass : IMyBaseClass {
    public void AddName<T>(T item) {
        // item could either be Book or Name
        var name = item.Name

        // or

        var name = item.FirstName + " " item.LastName;
    }
}
```

In the base class, how do I determine which type of `T` (Book or Author) is being passed in? And based on that I need to construct the `name` variable. Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: If `AddName` has different implementations for different derived types, it sounds like you want to make it abstract or virtual . If you find your self wanting to call `typeof(T)` its it becomes exceedingly likely that you don't want generics at all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking type parameter of a generic method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004508/checking-type-parameter-of-a-generic-method-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Another option could be to create overloads of the method for each type you want to support. Although it's hard to determine if an alternative solution would work without knowing more about how this code is going to be used

Answer (score 0):

While both your hierarchy and your use of generics seem highly dubious, the simple answer to your question is that you perform a runtime type test just as you would on the generically typed parameter, just as your would on other value

```
public class MyBaseClass : IMyBaseClass
{
    public void AddName<T>(T item)
    {
        // item could either be Book or Author
        var name = item switch
        {
            Author a => $"{a.FirstName} {a.LastName}",
            Book b => b.Name,
            _ => throw new ArgumentException(nameof(item), $"Invalid type: {a?.GetType()}")
        };
    }
}
```

As others already pointed out, however, since you only support a fixed set of types, overloads would be more appropriate.

```
public class MyBaseClass : IMyBaseClass
{
    public void AddName(Author author)
    {
        var name = $"{author.FirstName} {author.LastName}";
    }
    public void AddName(Book book) {
        var name = book.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you're better off moving the generic type parameter from the method to the type itself. You're writing a `BookTest` and the test is associated with `Book` then it's more natural to define your type like this: `class BookTest : MyBaseClass<Book>`.

So here are the base classes:

```
public interface IMyBaseClass<T>
{
    void AddName(T item);
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass<T> : IMyBaseClass<T>
{
    protected abstract string GetName(T item);
    
    public void AddName(T item)
    {
        var name = this.GetName(item);
    }
}
```

Then you write your tests like this:

```
public class BookTest : MyBaseClass<Book>
{
    protected override string GetName(Book item)
    {
        return item.Name;
    }
}

public class AuthorTest : MyBaseClass<Author>
{
    protected override string GetName(Author item)
    {
        return $"{item.FirstName} {item.LastName}";
    }
}
```

It's all strongly-typed and each class has a clear responsibility.